# Office 365 - Disable automatic replies to spcific addresses

Tags: microsoft-office-365

How do I disable organization wide all automatic replies to specific email address? We have one ticketing system which is getting those automatic replies now. The ticketing system is outside our Office 365 domain. I want to exclude that address from everyone's automatic replies, like a "do not send automatic replies to this address" rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a transport rule to do this. In the Office 365 portal, go to the [Exchange Admin Center](http://outlook.office365.com/ecp) and select Mail Flow. In the rules section, click the `+` to create a new blank rule.

To create a more than one condition, you need to click on `More options...` about half-way down the pop-up window.

It should look something like this:

[image]

Make sure the rule has a high enough priority that it doesn't get blocked by any other transport rules.